# Spanning set and Subset

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

The set
$$V = \{(a+2b+3c,3a+b+4c,4a+3b+7c)\ \ a,b,c \ \in \mathbb{R}: \}$$

forms a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$.

(a) Show that $S = \{(1,3,4),(2,1,3),(3,4,7)\}$ is a spanning set for $V$.

I know that $a+2b+3c = 1$ from vector $1, 2$ from vector $2$ and $3$ from vector $3$ and so on for the other two as well.

What I am unsure of is how to present this. How should I prove this?

(b) Find a *subset* of S which is a basis for V. Hence, find the dimension of V.

 How would I find the subset?

(I have done the first two)

(c) Let $\mathcal B$ be the basis from part (b). Find $[v]_\mathcal{B}$ where $v=(3,2,5).$

How would I do part (c)?

Comment: Hint: $(a)$. Is clear. For (b) note that $(3,4,7)=(1,3,4)+(2,1,3)$.

Answer (score 0):

So the subset is a linear transform, thus a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$, as:
$$
\left.\left\{
a\begin{pmatrix}
1\\
3\\
4\\
\end{pmatrix}+
b\begin{pmatrix}
2\\
1\\
3\\
\end{pmatrix}+
c\begin{pmatrix}
3\\
4\\
7\\
\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 & 3 \\
 3 & 1 & 4 \\
 4 & 3 & 7 \\\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}a\\ b\\ c\end{pmatrix}\right|a,b,c\in\mathbb{R}\right\}
$$
And 
$$
\det \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 & 3 \\
 3 & 1 & 4 \\
 4 & 3 & 7 \\\end{pmatrix}=0\qquad \text{rank}\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 & 3 \\
 3 & 1 & 4 \\
 4 & 3 & 7 \\\end{pmatrix}=2
$$
It forms a 2-dimensional subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$. Two base vectors are 
$$
\mathbf{x}_1=\begin{pmatrix}
1\\
3\\
4\\
\end{pmatrix}\qquad \mathbf{x}_2=\begin{pmatrix}
2\\
1\\
3\\
\end{pmatrix}
$$
as they are linearly independent

Answer (score 0):

For question b), use row reduction:
$$\begin{bmatrix}1&2&3\\3&1&4\\4&3&7\end{bmatrix}\rightsquigarrow\begin{bmatrix}1&2&3\\0&-5&-5\\0&-5&-5\end{bmatrix}\rightsquigarrow\begin{bmatrix}1&2&3\\0&1&1\\0&0&0\end{bmatrix}\rightsquigarrow\begin{bmatrix}1&0&1\\0&1&1\\0&0&0\end{bmatrix}$$
This proves $\dim V=2$, and the first two vectors are a basis for $V$.